# USB-C PD Smartphone

Tags: pcb, soldering, usb-c, board, breakout

My scenario: USB-C 5V smartphone charger is connected via USB-C cable to an breakout board. Both breakout boards are soldered together (All A Pins to A and all B to B). So basically I only extended the USB cable. But why is my smartphone not charging trough this? If I connect some Wemos Lolin development board, it's powering on and running fine?

[image: USB-C Breakout]

Comment: Are you sure the USB signalling involved in PD handshaking survives that mess of non-constant impedance wires? Are you sure you didn't short two pins together when soldering?

Comment: Yes, I tested all connections for shorts. You think it's because of the different length of the wires? Hadn't tought this would be the problem.

Comment: The different length, and also the uncontrolled dimensions.

Comment: Are you sure those are _just_ breakout boards, and there are no pulldown resistors on CC1/CC2? Aside from that, the soldering could be better, but if neither of those ideas explain it then I suspect signal integrity like @Hearth. I think in theory though this should be possible. The phone should charge (slowly) even if only VBUS, GND, and CC1/CC2 are connected! But **not** if other signals are connected _wrongly_.

Comment: the labels on the solder pads do not match up

Comment: You should have pre-applied solder to the wires. Doing so will prevent the stands from spreading out like on the picture, which in turn is a common cause for shorts. Through-hole would probably have been a better idea in this case. Or maybe some card edge board-to-wire connector. Don't plug your expensive phone into this you might fry it! Also don't work with electronics on top of a textile carpet! I'd recommend to slowly back away from this project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, such an adapter with two Type-C receptacles should not exist, because it allows you to extend the connection with two Type-C cables.

Or rather, does not allow extending, if you connect incorrect cables together or the cables are flipped incorrectly.

If you make such an adapter that should not be made, it can't be wired one-to-one like you now have wired it. The resulting adapter will also be extremely difficult to use, as depending on what kind of cables you use, they must be connected with correct flip orientation, or just won't work because certain active cables cannot be extended.

If you need a long cable for phone charging, buy a long cable. Don't make an adapter that allows connections that are not allowed in the standard.

Having said that, chinese online shops do sell adapters like what you are trying to make, the problem is, they still allow users to make connections that are dangerous or not allowed in the standard, so these adapters should not be made, sold or used.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. My goal was not to only extend the cable. I'm building an case for my phone. The case will also have an development board integrated. My goal was to use an USB-C port on the bottom of the case and connect them internally with the phone and the development board to provide power to both devices. I never did this with USB-C but with micro USB. My first try was to connect the VCC, GND and CC Pins, but this did not work. So my second attempt was to connect all together and (extend) the hole cable.